# Is there a way to add code to each instance of a regex match on the fly?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, each

Let's say I have a block of text and I want to replace each instance of the word "the" with an indexed number.

For example...

"The great white shark is the father of bite theory."

would become...

"0 great white shark is 1 fa2r of bite 3ory."

I'm looking for something like:
myText.match(/the/gi).each(function(i){
 //?
});

jquery solutions welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sYQgb/1/

```
var i = -1;
myText = myText.replace(/the/gi, function(){ return ++i; });
```

Comment: One of my favorite features. Note that the function provided is passed an argument list that's basically the same as the array returned from the "exec" function. The first argument is the whole match, and subsequent arguments are captured groups. (I know you know that @patrick dw I just added that for the young people reading these answers.)

Comment: @Pointy: Very much worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceText(text, splitArg) {
    //var text ="axaxa";
    var parts = text.split(splitArg);

    var replaced = "";
    var part;
    for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
        part = parts[i]
        if(i > 0)
            replaced += i-1;

        replaced+=part;

    }
    return replaced;
}


function writeLine(text) {
     document.write("<p>"+text+" &nbsp;</p>");   
}

writeLine(replaceText("axa", "x"));
writeLine(replaceText("axaxa", "x"));
writeLine(replaceText("axaxxa", "x"));
writeLine(replaceText("axaxxa", /x+/));//**using a regex!**
writeLine(replaceText("", "x"));
writeLine(replaceText("aa", "x"));

//output:
//a0a  
//a0a1a  
//a0a12a  
//a0a1a  
// 
//aa
```

In case you want to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/QFUWG/